# What is the exterior normal to the boundary of a Riemannian manifold?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, vector-fields

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold with boundary $\partial M$. Let $p \in \partial M$ and in local coordinates $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ near $p = (0,\ldots,0)$ the manifold $M$ is given by $\{x_n \geqslant 0\}$. What is the exterior normal to $M$ at point $p$? Is it $\bigl(-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\bigr)$? Or it is a vector in the orthogonal complement to the span of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}$, $\ldots$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{n-1}}$ with respect to the metric $g$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess it is a (unit ?) vector orthogonal to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$, $j<n$ such that its scalar product with $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}$ is negative.

The other definition you proposed ($-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}$) would depend on the coordinates.

Comment: On the other hand, we can start with a conormal vector $dx_n$ (it has the invariant definition) and raise it indices, but here I see a problem with the notion "exterior"

Comment: Is there an invariant definition of $dx_n$?

Comment: Those covectors from $T^*_p M$ that vanish on $T_p \partial M$

Comment: I think that if you do this (dualize this by "rising the indices" by the use of the metric) you get the same vector as I described in my answer.

Comment: If $T_p^*\partial M$ is the set of all covectors in $T_p^*M$ that vanish on $\partial M$ (a one-dimensional space), then your vector is the dual of a generator of this space. Whatever you do, you cannot define your "exterior normal" without the use of the metric. There is not an invariant expression using "only coordinates and not the metric."

Comment: (Just another remark: I still don't completely agree that $dx_n$ is independent on the coordinates. True, in any coordinates $dx_n$ is zero on $\partial M$, but $dx'_n$ can still be a scalar multiple of $dx_n$. You could, however, define a "natural" form $dx_n$ to be the differential of the distance function from the boundary.)

Comment: Sure, I mean its span rather than $dx_n$ itself.

Answer (score 2):

Giving explicit expressions to what was said in the first answer: If you have a Riemannian manifold $M^n$ with boundary, take any local embedding at the boundary into euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Then the outward pointing normal vector $\nu_g$ with respect to the metric $g$ can be optained by the euclidean outward pointing normal vector $\nu$ with the following formula:
$$\nu_{g,i}=\frac{g^{ij}\nu_j}{(\nu_k g^{kl}\nu_l)^{1/2}}$$
Using the inverse of the metric tensor (which itself is symmetric and positive definite) at the boundary, in other notation: 
$$\nu_g=\frac{g^{-1}\cdot\nu}{(\nu^T\cdot g^{-1}\cdot \nu)^{1/2}}$$
Note that it is unital, $|\nu_g|_g=1$, that is is $g$-orthogonal to the boundary. (Let $E$ be any vector in $T\partial M$, then $<E,\nu_g>_g=\frac{1}{(\nu^T\cdot g^{-1}\cdot \nu)^{1/2}}\cdot E^T\cdot g \cdot g^{-1}\cdot\nu=0$, by the fact that $\nu$ is normal w.r.t euclidean metric.) Also, it is outward-pointing, that is into the same Halfspace as $\nu$:
$$<\nu_g,\nu>_{\text{euclidean}}\;=\sqrt{\nu^T\cdot g^{-1}\nu}\quad>0$$ Thus it satisfies all three conditions for the outward pointing normal vector. In your question, $\nu=-e_n$ and therefore $\nu_{g,i}=-\frac{g^{in}}{\sqrt{g^{nn}}}$. Pull this back and use the metric on 1-forms to rewrite: $$\nu_g(p)=-\frac{<\operatorname{d}\!x^i,\operatorname{d}\!x^n>\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}}{\sqrt{<\operatorname{d}\!x^n,\operatorname{d}\!x^n>}}$$

Comment: Answers are presented with the accepted first and then according to score, both might change, so referring to some "first" answer, is a bad idea (if even correct) as it might be presented below your answer which will confuse future readers.